# Insert function in a Binary Search Tree

Tags: python, insert, binary-search-tree

My insert method in my Binary search tree is creating problems. I'm getting separate nodes instead of one. What have I done incorrectly?

```
class Node:

def __init__(this,key,value):
    this.key = key
    this.value = value
    this.left = null
    this.right = null
def insert(this,root,key,value):
    if(root == null):
        root = Node(key,value)
        return root
    elif(root.key < key):
        root.left =  root.insert(root.left,key,value)
        return root
    elif(root.key > key):
        root.right =  root.insert(root.right,key,value)
        return root
    else:
        print("Data already exists!")
        return root
```

Comment: Are you saying that `node.insert` is overwriting root node, with your new values?

Comment: Yes. They are not overwriting it, and instead creating another one instead of filling in the root node.

Comment: Where are they creating this another one? Can you show the complete `node` class?

Comment: Yes, I will post it now.

Comment: Post it in the question.

Comment: Edit your code above!

Comment: Sorry. I have edited the code above

Comment: I just ran your code in python 3.3 , it looks fine , are you sure, you are getting issues? If so, which python version is it?

Comment: It is 3.3. Let me try again and double check

Comment: first time that i see someone uses "this" instead of "self". :P

Comment: Sorry. The first language I learned was Java.

Comment: Still isn't working. After inserting I'm getting this: Node data=[1, 1]
Left:None
Right:None

Answer (score 2):

Your code does a strange modification along the search path. E.g., look at the line

```
 root.left = root.insert(root.left,key,value)
```

It says "the new left child of the node is what's returned by `root.insert`".

So let's say it continues down 30 more levels, and then it finds the key. It executes

```
else:
    print("Data already exists!")
    return root
```

So that updates all sorts of things up. Probably not what you want.

---

You can solve this issue by changing

```
root.left = root.insert(root.left,key,value)
```

to

```
return root.insert(root.left,key,value)
```

Comment: No , that is not the issue, his recursion is good and it would work correctly.

Comment: So does that mean that my else statement shouldn't return root? That's true, I'll delete that part then.

Comment: On the contrary, it can return the root; it's just that other cases along the search path shouldn't assign the return value as their children. See update to answer.

Comment: I'm still unable to get the correct answer using the changes above. My new output is:   '1,1' , none, none